# How do I verify that certain method was called on javascript object with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, mocking, assertion

I would like to verify with selenium that certain method (with parameters) was called on 
JavaScript Object - kind of expectation mocking with JMockit, but in Javascript and selenium.

Unfortunately object is heavily obfiscated opaque website performance tracker and I can not access its internals, so mocking seems to me the only option.   Or do I miss something obvious?

Update:  after thinking about it, it seems to me that solution could be:
 - wait for HTML to load completely 
 - remove certain script tag  containing performance tracker
 - create javascript mock object behaving like tracker but recording  invocations for later use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsMockito is obviously the most robust solution there is. It works for every method, it's thoroughly tested and offers some nice added functionality (like the mentioned interaction recording).

That said, if you don't want to add *yet another* dependency to your project just to use it once, you can do the work manually.

```
window.origWwa = window.wwa;
window.wwa = function() {
    if (arguments[0] === 'Trefferliste Webadresse') {
        window.wwaFired = true;
    }
    window.origWwa.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

... do your work ...

```
if (!window.wwaFired) {
    // do something, either throw an error or console.log("oops")
}
```

---

If the script to be run is in a `<script>` tag and the browser of your choice is Firefox, you can hook the [`onafterscriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onafterscriptexecute) event by any function. It's shorter, but I think you can't make sure the right argument was called:

```
document.getElementById('script').onafterscriptexecute = function() {
    window.wwaFired = true;
};
```

Comment: Nice solution - will work fine for single invocation but for complex interactions mocking is better

Comment: Absolutely. It's a simple one-timer. If I had to use it twice or wanted something more, I'd take JsMockito.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, finally got it.  Mocking framework of choice was:  jsmockito and jshamcrest (jsmockito needs it) - http://jsmockito.org/

And it was peace of cake.

Spy on existing object:

```
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>window.wwa = JsMockito.spy(window.wwa$); </td>
<td>mockedWipe</td>
```

...  do whatever necessary

and verify it:

```
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>JsMockito.verify(window.wwa$).logAction('Trefferliste Webadresse');</td>
<td></td>
```

Cave at's:

- window scoped variables are  in namespace **window**
- evaluation valie from verification step can be ignored,  as you get an exception if call is not satisfied
- do not forget to add js libraries to your selenium ide or test  driver

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the function to call another function to work with selenium (IDK how SELENIUM works)

```
Function.prototype.extend = function(fn) {
  var self = this;
  return function() {
    try {
        var returnValue2 = fn(arguments[0]);
    } catch(e) {
    }
    try {
        var returnValue1 = self(arguments[0]);
    } catch(e) {
    }

    return returnValue1 && returnValue2;
  };
};

var object = {a_function:function(arg){
  alert(arg)
}};

object.a_function('simple'); // alerts "simple"
object.a_function = object.a_function.extend(function(arg){
  alert('prealert for '+arg)
});

object.a_function('simple'); // alerts "prealert for simple" and then alerts "simple"
```